# Migration from angular 1.2 to 1.5

Tags: angularjs

Currently I am using angular v1.2.26. When I upgraded it to v1.5.0(or v.1.4.8), the application stopped working.

What are the changes in the existing code of v1.2.26, I should not be missing, to make the application work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Migration Guide - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration

See the change log

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

An easier way is to see where your code fails, debug a bit and hit the nail. There are no huge changes between the versions in question.

Answer (score 7):

There's now a guide available https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration - probably slightly less tedious than reading every single ChangeLog

Answer (score 0):

Although, your question is not a good candidate for StackOverflow questions but you should read the ChangeLog to see the breaking changes and fixes in each release after `v1.2.26` to `v1.5.0`.

See the changes https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: But won't that be too tedious to do, checking all the changes. Why don't we have a clean way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look if this may help you:

http://www.diatomenterprises.com/migration-history-from-angularjs-1-3-to-1-5-and-then-2-0/

I can assist you in migration from 1.3/1.4 to 1.5 since did it a few times on different projects and all went smooth. Of course there're some tricks to do, but in general nothing breaking.